# How to split line into (key, value) pair with fixed size key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am new to Apache Spark, I have a file, where every sentences in which first 10 characters is a key and rest is a value, how do I apply spark sort on it to extract the first 10 characters of each sentence as a key and rest as a data, so in the end I get a [key,value] pair Rdd as a output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` with `take` and `drop` should do the trick:

```
rdd.map(line => (line.take(10), line.drop(10)))
```

Sort:

```
val sorted = rdd.sortByKey
```

Prepare output:

```
val lines = sorted.map { case (k, v) => s"$k $v" }
```

Comment: `rdd.map(_.splitAt(10))`